# How to implement external auth in KONG?

Tags: authentication, flask, authorization, microservices, kong

I'm using [KONG API Gateway](https://konghq.com/), and I want to implement JWT authentication as separate microservice (not using KONG plugin), now I can easily register this service with KONG, and so users can register and login. Assume an authenticated user had sent a request with a token attached in the header, how to make KONG forwards the request to the authentication service first, then if it is valid the request is forwarded to the requested service?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can (But I have not used them) there is as far as I know two options:

1. https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/openid-connect/  **Enterprise**
2. https://github.com/aunkenlabs/kong-external-auth **Free**