# Kong custom auth layer and rate limiting

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I would like to use Kong to protect some services. But I already used an idm for the user management.

The user gets a token from the idm and puts it in the header when he requests the kong gateway. For this I would write a plugin that does this. The plugin would then request the idm. As an answer you get from the idm if the user is allowed to make this request and the user id that the user has in the idm. So the user is only registered in the idm and not as a consumer in Kong. If I want to use a rate limit now, the plugin description says `If the underlying Service/Route (or deprecated API entity) has no authentication layer, the client IP address will be used, otherwise the Consumer will be used if an authentication plugin has been configured.`

Is it now possible to use the user id from the idm to limit the rate limit in?

I already found:

- [How to implement external auth in KONG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268652/how-to-implement-external-auth-in-kong)
- [Custom Authentication Service in Kong API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619686/custom-authentication-service-in-kong-api-gateway?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but I could not find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to set the `config.limit_by` to header and `config.header_name` to a custom name([configuration](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/rate-limiting/#parameters)). So the plugin needs to set a custom header e.g. 'x-user-id' to the id given from the idm. You have to make sure, that your plugin runs before the rate limiting plugin. You can look this up [here](https://docs.konghq.com/2.1.x/plugin-development/custom-logic/#plugins-execution-order) ( > 901). Now just set the `config.header_name` to x-user-id and rate limiting works. I couldn't find an other solution.

Comment: How can I add/append user_id in the request header?
I wrote a kong plugin in GoLang

Comment: kong.ServiceRequest.SetHeader should do it